# Do I need a connection to use ActiveRecordObject.new?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, initialization

Can you create and initialize an ActiveRecord object like this?

```
exercise = Exercise.new
exercise.name = "foo"
exercise.description = "bar"
exercise.unit_id = 123
```

I am trying to do this and I keep getting

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/base.rb:1271:in `columns'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/base.rb:3014:in `attributes_from_column_definition_without_lock'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:55:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/base.rb:2434:in `initialize'
 main.rb:14:in `new'
```

I just want to create and initialize the object then call a `.save` method. If I am going about this incorrectly, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer: Yes, you need a connection!**

You cannot (generally) use ActiveRecord unless there is a connection.

The set of attributes on the object is determined by the columns on the table. Which means you can't use the object unless you have the connection.

In any case what would happen after calling `exercise.save` if there is no connection?

So if you only need the validation, you can reuse ActiveSupport::Validation on a transient class.

Comment: +1 The only answer so far that answers the question presented. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had created a save_to_database() method that opened a conneciton and saved the object to the correct table.  I didn't realize that AR needed to read the table to know what columns it has.

Answer (score 0):

This would imply that Rails cannot connect to your database. Ensure your database server is on (if applicable), and that your [`config/database.yml` file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of your code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "mysql",
  :host => "localhost",
  :username => "<your database username>",
  :password => "<your database password>",
  :database => "<your database name>"
)
```

The above code should establish an ActiveRecord database connection to your database. You can check out the manual for it here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection. Good luck!